# IE9 - acceptable frameset replacement

Tags: html, iframe, internet-explorer-9, frame, frames

I have a site that I'm working on that has a lot of framesets in it.  However, since IE9 (HTML5), framesets have been deprecated and it throws me into quirks mode which slows down the loading of my page.  Basically, I'm looking for an acceptable alternative to framesets that is HTML5 compatible.  Thanks for any responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply replace frameset with iframes. Use CSS and maybe some JavaScript to recreate the same layout.

Answer (score 2):

Were you using frames in order to provide distinction between different sections of your page, i.e. a frame for a left nav column, a frame for a header, and a frame for the content? If so, you can accomplish the same effect by using `div` elements and css styling.

Comment: I was using frames in this way, but they reference other pages that have the information contained in them.  (All frames in the frameset use the src attribute)

Comment: Oh ok, so if I understand correctly, you were effectively using the frames as a templating engine in order to reduce code redundancy. If that is the case, would a templating engine work for you in this situation?

Comment: It's not quite a templating engine because it's the same page just included in different formats.  For example, I have a descriptor page that in some cases is on the right side of the form and in others is on the left side.  The frames have allowed me to include this description on multiple pages throughout my product.

Comment: A templating engine is probably overkill anyway. I don't know if this is the best solution, but you could use JavaScript to dynamically inject HTML nodes before the document loads. Using php is also an option.

Comment: I thought about php but the product is actually written in asp.Net.  iframes still work but I'm not sure how to group and format them other than using tables, which is still an option, just a pain.